# mydatepicker disableSince option in case of date of birth validation

Tags: angular, datepicker, date

I am using mydatepicker https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepicker for my calender field . The field is Date of Birth field. As its logically clear , i need to disable the future dates by getting the current date . I have gone through the doc . It has disableSince option with year, month and day parameters. I am unsure how to pass current date + 1 ( +1 because i need the current date to be in enabled state, only the future dates should be disabled ) to disableSince option .

```
 <my-date-picker name="DOB" class="form-control calander required mousechange customCalender" [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
                      formControlName="DOB"   placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY" ></my-date-picker>


public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: 'dd / mmm / yyyy',
    disableSince: {year: 2018, month: 6, day: 1}
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should Do `(new Date()).getDate() + 1` to disable future dates excluding todays date. And also do not hard code month and year.

```
private today = new Date();
public myDatePickerOptions = {
   dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
   disableSince: {year: this.today.getFullYear(), month: this.today.getMonth() + 1, day: this.today.getDate() + 1}
};
```

Check the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpy8kj)